# My background image is purple

Tags: image

Every time I add a image background, it appears purple.
I even tried re-adding it.

It started happening yesterday and when I came back to blender again today, the problem is still there.

And I also realise that all my blend files are also effected. Last time, i could see the image, now not anymore.

im kind of a beginner so I might have done something wrong or is it just a bug.

[image]

Comment: The File > External Data menu has two operations for helping diagnose missing or broken file paths. It's unclear from your description "what changed" from "last time", but try the 'Report Missing Files' option for starters to see where Blender is looking for the images.

Comment: It sounds as if you may have changed the location of your image and texture files outside Blender if it's happening with other files too.

Comment: ... or have you moved your blend files/folder? Blender stores the path to the images relative to the blend file (e.g. ../../../textures/texture1.png). If you have moved the main folder of the blend files or the textures or have renamed the "textures" folder then the path is breaks.